# How can I efficiently patch an external library and compile it in a Makefile for a C project?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, static-libraries, patch

I'm working on a C project which needs an external open source library.
In particular, it needs a version I patched myself in order to add some needed features.

At the moment I'm using a Makefile which expects a statically compiled version of the patched library inside the `./lib` folder (let's call it `libpatched.a`), and the corresponding header files in `./include/libpatched`.
The following are the main parts of the aforementioned Makefile:

```
EXECNAME=MyExecutable

CC=gcc

SRC_DIR=src
OBJ_DIR=obj

SRC=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

OBJ=$(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

CFLAGS += -Wall -O2 -Iinclude -Iinclude/libpatched
LDFLAGS += -Llib
LDLIBS += -lpatched

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXECNAME)

$(EXECNAME): $(OBJ_CC)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o
```

This Makefile is working correctly; however, I was looking for a more flexible solution, which does not need any statically compiled library before `make` is called.
What I would like to accomplish is having a Makefile which does something like:

1. Download a specific version of the original library (in order to never have any compatibility problem)
2. Apply a patch using `patch` and a diff file (`.patch`)
3. Compile the patched library (either statically or dynamically) for the current platform, using `cmake`, as required by the original library
4. Compile my project, using `libpatched`

Are these steps valid in your opinion, or is there a much better way to handle this need for a patched library?

If yes, as I'm not an expert at all in creating Makefiles, is there an easy way to reach this goal by simply leveraging on a properly written Makefile?

Which could be the best way to do so?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done exactly this before, when building cross compiler etc with my patches for my operating system kernel. You can use the `wget` or `curl` commands in the Makefile. For  example something like

```
# foo.tar.gz needs to be downloaded
foo.tar.gz:
    wget https://download.source.from/here/foo.tar.gz -O foo.tar.gz

# the makefile requires the downloaded file.
foo_src/CMakeLists.txt: foo.tar.gz
    mkdir -p foo_src
    cd foo_src && tar xfz ../foo.tar.gz

# patch the library if flag not present
foo_patched.flag:
    cd foo_src && patch -p1 ../foo.patch
    touch foo_patched.flag

# this depends on patching
libpatched.a: foo_src/CMakeLists.txt foo_patched.flag 
    cd foo_src && cmake
    cp foo_src/libfoo.a libpatched.a
```

The Makefile format is very simple - unlike CMake! - the rules just say: "to generate the file on the left, please build the prerequisites on the right side first. Then execute these commands to actually generate the file on the left hand side"